# Регулярное выражение для комментария

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос. Возникла необходимость в большом количестве исходного кода найти и заменить строку "Text", за исключением этой строки в коментариях. Комментарии имеются в виду обычные два слеша // либо xml комментарии <!--.

Например:

```
Console.WriteLine("Text");  // нужно менять так как "Text" встречается в коде
// Text  - тут менять не нужно так как строка начинается с двух слешей
string str = "text"; // не нужно менять, так как text написано с маленькой буквы
<!-- some text --> // не нужно менять так как строка начинается с <!--
```

Я, к сожалению, не силен в регулярных выражениях, поэтому не знаю даже, как это сделать. ((

Comment: А не прроще заменить "Text" вместе с кавычками на "any text" опять же с киавычками. Или комментарии тоже с кавычками встречаются?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ли заменять, если `string s = "<!-- Text внутри строки в коде -->";` или `return 1; // Text не сначала строки` или `<!-- Text` (нет `-->` на той же строке)? Что насчёт триграфов `??/` (если они есть в языке) или другие возможности по вводу символов, например, `\u003e`? Если есть возможность, то лучше воспользоваться родным токенайзером, компилятором, который позволяет обходить код как структуру (например, дерево -- ast) программно, чтобы все крайние случаи охватить.